# Get selected items from combo box

Tags: java, swing

I have a combo box that contains data from an array. I want to be able to get the the selected name in the `JComboBox` and print it to a text file. The problem is that the name wont write to the text file.

Array code:

```
    public class readfiles {
    String [] names = new String[15];
    int i = 0;
    private Scanner readNames;

    //Opens the file
    public void openFile() {
        try {
            readNames = new Scanner(new File("ChildName.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not locate the data file!");
        }
    }

    //Reads the names in the file
    public void readFile() {
        while(readNames.hasNext()) {
            names[i] = readNames.next();
            System.out.println(names[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Closes the file 
    public void closeFile() {
        readNames.close();
    }
}
```

ComboBox code:

```
//JComboBox for selecting child
JLabel selectChildName = new JLabel("Please Select Your Child:");
sPanel.add(selectChildName);
readfiles readNames = new readfiles();
readNames.openFile();
readNames.readFile();
readNames.closeFile();
JComboBox<String> selectChild = new JComboBox<String>(readNames.names);
sPanel.add(selectChild);
```

And finally this is what I am doing to write the selected name to a text file.

```
bw.write(selectChild.getSelectedIndex());
```

**UPDATE**

Used:

```
bw.write(selectChild.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: If you want to get the selected item use `JComboBox.getSelectedItem` and not `JComboBox.getSelectedIndex`. Btw your `readFiles` class will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when file `ChildNames.txt` contains more than 15 entries.

Comment: @ArcticLord Ideally when a new entry is added to the text file, it is added to the array even if it does go over 15 entries. but not sure?

Comment: No. Your array can store 15 entries only. And your index increases with each name that was read. The 16th name will be stored at index 15 and that will result in an exception. Maybe you should use a `List` instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need `JComboBox#getSelectedItem()` instead of `JComboBox#getSelectedIndex()`. As it is a String, it should be printed within the file.

> Returns the current selected item.

Do not forget to also use a `ItemListener` with your `JComboBox`